# Как перебирать значения атрибутра html тегов, пока не найдешь нужный?

Tags: javascript, html, css, атрибуты, перебор

У меня есть теги, которым я присваиваю индексы в атрибуте data-index. Мне нужно перебрать потом значения атрибутов, и при нахождении соответствующего, я смог совершить какое то действие.

Вот что я пытался сделать, но не получилось

```
var indexTag = document.querySelectorAll('.input__item');
var tag = document.querySelector('.input__item');
for(var i = 0; i < indexTag.length; i++) {
    indexTag[i].setAttribute('data-index', i%indexTag.length);
    
    var attr = tag.getAttribute('data-index')

}
```

Comment: indexTag содержит все теги input, а tag только первый. вы в цикле задаете всем тегам, а читаете только из первого. напишите 2 функции: первая записывает в атрибуты (ее работу можно проверить инспектируя страницу), а вторая читает и выводит их в консоль.

Comment: Если честно вообще не понимаю зачем перебором искать нужный, если можно просто написать правильный селект?

Comment: а вот эта запись зачем - i%indexTag.length ?